# How to open Anaconda Navigator in Linux Ubuntu via terminal

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, navigator

I failed to open Anaconda Navigator via terminal.
i use the command:

- anaconda-navigator
  didnt work
  How to open Anaconda Navigator in linux ubuntu via terminal?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Are you sure that Anaconda is properly installed?

Answer (score 1):

1. open with terminal directory /home/?????/anaconda3/bin
2. try theses commands
3. export PATH=/home/?????/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
4. conda --version
5. anaconda-navigator

Comment: There is no "bin" directory under "anaconda3".

Answer (score -1):

Conda command is already installed in your system, so you just need to specify the program you want run thru Conda:

```
conda run anaconda-navigator
```

Another way to do it is to activate the environment and execute the navigator thru the running process:

```
conda activate base

anaconda-navigator
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: "conda" command not found.

Comment: conda --version?